# Android consulting Mysql and equality with String

Tags: android, mysql

When I Read of a BD of mysql, I try compare a String (User and Pasw) enter for the user with the date of BD.
But if i put == never said my is equal.

i have a Variable box:

```
package clases;

import bdMySQL.BDUsuarios;

public class Usuarios {

    private String Usuario;
    private String Password;
    private String Rol;

    public Usuarios( String i, String n, String rol ){
        this.Usuario = i;
        this.Password = n;
        this.Rol = rol;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return Usuario;
    }

    public String getRol(String Usuario, String Password) {
        if (Usuario == this.Usuario && Password == this.Password){
            return this.Rol;
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

And The consult of BD is correct.

When I lunch my main program:

```
public class PruebaMySQLActivity extends Activity {


public List<Usuarios> Usuarios;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button btnConectar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConectar);
    final TextView txtMensaje = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);

    btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Usuarios = BDUsuarios.getDatosUsuarios();
            String rol = "";
            String Usuario = "miuser";
            String Pasw = "mipasw";
            int i = 1;
            while (i < Usuarios.size() &&  rol == ""){
                //Toast t=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(i) + " " + familias.get(i).getUsuario() + " " + familias.get(i).getPassword() + " " + familias.get(i).getrol2()  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //t.show();
                rol = Usuarios.get(i).getRol(Usuario, Pasw);
                i= i + 1;
            }

            txtMensaje.setText(rol);

        }
    }); 
}
```

}

The toast show me perfectly all data, but when I tried to do the "==" not found.
And i tried to:

```
Usuario.equals(this.Usuario)
```

and not found.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java. check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing two string you can use equals() or equalsorIgnore() methods.E.g.

```
if(s1.equals(s2))
{
}
```

instead of

```
if(s1==s2)
    {
    }
```